# How can I enable logging in android chromium？

Tags: android, debugging, chromium

I've been recently studying webkit-related stuff on ICS. How can I enable the original logging in chrome stack(code in external/chromium)?

---

I know how to print my own log onto `Logcat`. But I need to see the debug level log to solve some problem.  Any advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess this tutorial on [chromium.org](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-android) or better [chromium.org # LogOutput](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-android#TOC-Log-output) should answer your question...